# On click of button in html page I need to generate pdf file along with content ,but images are not showing in generated pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js'></script>   
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {

    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {

        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
});

</script>
```

When I click on generate pdf button pdf file is downloading , but images are not displaying.

```
<div id="content">
   <img src="file:///C:/Users/lakshmi_priya/Desktop/datepicker.png" width="100" height="100" />asfasdfasdfasdsfsdfasdfasdfasdfa
</div>


<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>


</body>
```

Comment: Iam not using the server response.I need to show th the data in the div with id="content".

Comment: How are you running this code? Do you have this mounted on a server? I see the image is pointing to a local file, and generally that's a bad idea for a web site.